# Frontend Customer Registration and newsletter subcription not working in magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento

I can't figure out what the real problem is..
When I click the link login in the header it takes me to the customer login page..
But on that page none of the buttons works after submitting the data..

1. Login button on customer login page does not work
2. Submit Button on create account page does not work..
3. Newsletter subcription button does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lad, have the same problem with newsletter.
Just installed the new version of Magento, 1.6.2.0 and didn't see the input.
Insert this:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer_newsletter" as="footer_newsletter" before="cms_footer_address"  template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

into /app/design/frontend/YOUR-PACKAGE/YOUR-THEME/layout/newsletter.xml into  block.
Then go to /app/design/frontend/YOUR-PACKAGE/YOUR-THEME/template/page/html/footer.phtml, find there this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

replace with this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_newsletter') ?>
```

It worked to me. I havent review login page, but I hope my advice with the newsletter will be useful. Good luck!